# Android Visualizer (Audio Effects) runtime exception on Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, exception, audio, visualizer

In the sample AudioFxDemo.java, provided with the SDK, I get a

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -4
```

when trying to create the android.media.audiofx.Visualizer

```
mVisualizer = new Visualizer(mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
```

(AudioFxDemo.java:173).

As far as I can see, the error originates in the [native code](http://android.yongbok.net/repository/frameworks/base/media/jni/audioeffect/android_media_Visualizer.cpp), (lines 266 ff.) An error also happens when trying to create the android.media.audiofx.Equalizer:

```
mEqualizer = new Equalizer(0, mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
```

(AudioFxDemo.java:98)

I get a

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Effect type: 0bed4300-ddd6-11db-8f34-0002a5d5c51b not supported.
```

I have declared the following permissions for my project:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

It seems to be a problem with the API level. I have no problems on Gingerbread (API Level 10). I have only tested on virtual devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the Emulator.  I have tested on an actual device running Android 4.0.3 and it worked just fine.

Comment: I encountered the same issue. I was having issued running on the emulator but did not experience them when running on an actual device.

Comment: i have implemented same thing. But it is crashing on Emulator and working perfect in real device. What should be cause of this issue?

Comment: I am having the same issue with real world device running Android 6.0 marshmallow. And I have added every required permission

Answer (score 2):

it seems issue on some android devices. I got this crash http://pastebin.com/7kqPbxkV on Lenovo  a369i SDK version 17. For now only thing i`ve found is to check if equalizer effect is supported on device:

```
boolean supports_equalizer=false;
AudioEffect.Descriptor [] effects = Equalizer.queryEffects();
for (AudioEffect.Descriptor lDescriptor:effects){
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=18) { //Equalizer present only starting with API 18. Cam try to hardcode its UUID
     if (AudioEffect.EFFECT_TYPE_EQUALIZER.equals(lDescriptor.uuid)){
        supports_equalizer=true;
     }
   }
}
```